# change web address and download - please advise

Tags: web, download

I am a complete novice, so please excuse me if the answer is already out there-as i don't have sufficient knowledge to make an accurate search.

I have a project where the CSV data i want is accessible from a web address such as www.xxxxxx.com/xxDATEFORMAT.  I want to know what i need to learn/do to basically automate the process of

changing the date in that web address 
and downloading the csv in a folder with file name as DATEFORMAT
then repeating the process for all dates back to some given date.

As far as i know this requires a script and some kind of loop...but i don't really know much more.  I guess it will require at least 2 dates to be specified, and it's trading data so it will exclude weekends, so i would be open to entering a list of dates somewhere.

OS is windows7 but could consider using a linux distro via windows virtual machine if that will work.

Any pointers would be really appreciated, however scant.
Cheers

Comment: What's your OS ? Can you use bash and wget ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on linux, you can use something like this in a `.sh` script :

```
DATE_PART=`date +%Y/%m/%d`
mkdir -p "/wheretostore/$DATE_PART"
cd "/wheretostore/$DATE_PART"
wget "http://www.xxxxxx.com/$DATE_PART/myfile.csv"
```

And you can call this script from [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Comment: Thanks, i'm on windows7 but will look into using linux on virtual machine and give this a go.  I assume if it looks for a weekend date it will return an error but will carry on once i ok it?

Comment: If the file isn't found, the script will end normally, no problem.

Comment: I don't think **I** would install a VM just for that. You could do this in a few lines of java or go. I just don't know how to configure a cron like tool on windows.

Comment: Not me (I use mostly linux). You may try to refine your initial question with tags like [powershell] or [Windows] but you may have to ask another very specific question like "How to plan web fetching on Powershell as could be done with cron and wget on linux ?".

Comment: OK, thanks.  As an offshoot you've actually got me really interested in linux and i've started learning some basic bash scripting in that - so thanks!  I just came across powershell tangentially and wondered whether that could do it.  Found a manual [the o'reilly cookbooks] which has a code for how to download a web page, i guess i just modify that with a conditional loop.  Anyhows thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm sincerely glad to have been able to get you interested in linux.